# Convert Rows in To Column

Tags: php, mysql

i have Two Table **Inquiry Table** and **Inquiry Quotation Table** i Upload The Data in To inquiry Table and send To multiple supplier and They Put Their Prices in **Inquiry Quotation Table** i am Getting The Data in row vs with supplier and supplier data  as Shown in Inquiry Quotation 
But i want To show The Supplier Name and its data in column vs Please Help me.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: This is a "pivot". You *can* do this in mysql, but I think it's much simpler and generally more flexible/scalable to do this in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a basic structure of your table and tested on it. Something like:

```
SELECT ET.enq_detail_id,ET.enq_id,EQ1.s_id, EQ1.enq_detail_id, EQ1.weight_per1000 , EQ2.s_id as s_id_2, EQ2.enq_detail_id as enq_detail_id_2, EQ2.weight_per1000 as weight_per1000_2

FROM EnqueryTable ET LEFT OUTER JOIN
      EnqueryQuoted EQ1 ON EQ1.enq_detail_id=ET.enq_detail_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
      EnqueryQuoted EQ2 ON EQ2.enq_detail_id=ET.enq_detail_id
WHERE EQ1.s_id=2 AND EQ2.s_id=4
```

Result is:

```
ENQ_DETAIL_ID   ENQ_ID  S_ID    WEIGHT_PER1000  S_ID_2   ENQ_DETAIL_ID_2     WEIGHT_PER1000_2
157             19      2       10              4        157                 10.4
158             19      2       157             4        158                 157
159             19      2       22              4        159                 22.5
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b90768/1).

Now add the required column names in this query.

Comment: @khan: Its a pleasure, my friend.

Comment: Raging Bull  if There are multiple S_ID Then what To Do?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Pivoting table ,
Lets check here some Pivoting [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629155/pivot-table-in-mysql-convert-to-pivot-table-with-values-in-varchar-format) 
Or 
[example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table).

Otherwise you can manage in your php server code by looping

Comment: Thanks Imran for response  i tried using for loop and while loop but i not get the answer is it possible that you also write a code?