# horizontal vertical data table php mysql

Tags: php, html

I Have code to show table horizontal.

i want can show table Table like this.

> ```
>                 12/15/2014 || 12/16/2014
> ```
>
> Rumah ATM              ...........|      YA..................||YA.............. etc

```html
</tr>
 <?php 
$nip= $_REQUEST["txtcar"];
include ("../connect.php");
$query1 = "SELECT ambilmk.tgl,ambilmk.nim,ambilmk.kodeMK,ambilmk.nilai,list.kom,list.id_check 
FROM ambilmk 
LEFT JOIN list
ON ambilmk.kodemk=list.id_check
where nim='1'
 ";
$hasil1 = mysql_query($query1);
$no = 1;
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($hasil1))
{?>
  <tr align="center">
    <td><?php echo $row1["tgl"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row1["kom"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row1["nilai"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Can You help to give code. display table vertical horizontal

Comment: So you want to basically do a pivot table from the data you are pulling in the query?

Comment: Why not simply get the data and display it the way you want using PHP ? MySQL is not on presentation layer, and in fact not so great at pivoting.

Comment: yes... i want show horizontally $row[tgl].based on vertically $row[kom]

Answer (score 0):

As in HTML-Table you need to code a ROW first then a second row AND you have a ROW but want to display in different rows VERTICALLY... So you need to store the rows in variables.

Let me show you how. Assume you have MySQL Row with 3 columns (as in your code), Then:

```
 $row_1='<tr align="center">';
 $row_2='<tr align="center">';
 $row_3='<tr align="center">';
 while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($hasil1))
 {
     $row_1.="<td>".$row1["tgl"]."</td>";
     $row_2.="<td>".$row1["kom"]."</td>";
     $row_3.="<td>".$row1["nilai"]."</td>";
 }
 echo $row_1."</tr>";
 echo $row_1."</tr>";
 echo $row_1."</tr>";
```

---

**EDIT: AS OP need Pivot**

[Reason of incorrectness for above answer:] If `group by` is required then its not possible by above code (I m leaving it for future users) & PIVOT is not supported in FREE MySQL...

AND

By static queries you can not do that UNLESS values of `tgl` are static/fixed. So you need to use **dynamic query** AND second option is to create **stored procedure**.

Both method are explained in this question: [Pivot table in MySQL - convert to pivot table with values in varchar format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629155/pivot-table-in-mysql-convert-to-pivot-table-with-values-in-varchar-format)

---

**EDIT 2: Got the way to do it by PHP after analyzing the above link:**

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT tgl FROM ambilmk WHERE nim='1';");
 $tgls_col="";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $tgls_col.=",MAX(CASE WHEN ambilmk.tgl = '".$row[0]."' THEN ambilmk.nilai END) `".$row[0]."`";
 }

 $query1 = "SELECT list.kom as Kom ".$tgls_col." FROM ambilmk LEFT JOIN list 
      ON ambilmk.kodemk=list.id_check where nim='1' GROUP BY ambilmk.tgl,list.kom;";
 $hasil1 = mysql_query($query1);

 $fields=mysql_fetch_fields($hasil1);
 echo '<tr>';
 foreach ($fields as $col) {
     echo '<th>'.$col->name.'</th>';
 }
 echo '</tr>';
 $fields=count($fields);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($hasil1)){
      echo '<tr>';
      for($I=0;$I<$fields;I++){
           echo "<td>".$row[$I].'</td>';
      }
      echo '</tr>';
 }
```

**HERE** you can switch between `list.kom` and `ambilmk.nilai` AND can change aggregation function `MAX` to any other you want like `COUNT` etc. ALSO toggle the order of columns in GROUP BY caluse to get desire result. **As your column names are in different language, that's why cant understands whats in those, so you need to do these suggested variations.** AND ALSO NOT ABLE TO TEST AS DONT HAVE YOUR TABLE STRUCTURE.

Comment: i dont understand. i just want Pivot table.where header group by tgl.

Comment: @Adeputratioaldino: If group by is required then its not possible by my answer & PIVOT is not supported in FREE MySQL... | By static queries you can not do that UNLESS values of `tgl` are static/fixed. AND second option is to create stored procedure. Look the edited answer for link to help you. :)

Comment: @Adeputratioaldino: You didn't understand coz in your mind/need `PIVOT` was there. Now see the edited answer. [AND INITIALLY, I just explained that MySQL returns rows horizontally, SO... to display those vertically you need to store in variables first then display]