# view all products using group by in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

i've this client who has a employee list and he wants to display all employees of same category(in group), i'm sorry if i'm not able to explain, i will try to explain

```
----------------------------
id | e_id | e_pos   | e_name
-----------------------------
 1 | 142  |   dev   | abc
 2 | 143  |  sr.dev | bac
 3 | 144  |  intern | jlk
 4 | 145  |   dev   | jlsd
 5 | 146  |   dev   | asdf
 6 | 147  |  sr.dev | adsc
 7 | 148  |  intern | mlkn
 8 | 149  |  sr.dev | vjll
 9 | 150  |   dev   | knmk
10 | 151  |   dev   | jlkm
----------------------------
```

how to show the output

`Number of dev(5)
 1) abc
 2) jlsd
 3) asdf
 4) knmk
 5) jlkm
 Number of intern(2)
 1) jlk
 2) mlkn
 Number of sr.dev(3)
 1) bac
 2) adsc
 3) vjll`

now the problem is i've tried this piece of code

```
$this->db->select('e_id,e_pos,e_name');
$this->db->group_by('e_pos');
$query = $this->db->get('emp'); // table name
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return $query->result();
}
```

but the above code is not working, it's just showing dev and number of dev, i want to see all dev data.

`dev`

**I'm using Codeigniter 2.2.0**

Comment: `pivot` might help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629155/pivot-table-in-mysql-convert-to-pivot-table-with-values-in-varchar-format

Comment: You have formed wrong query here. It will not work using group by clause.

Comment: You can use order by clause on 'e_pos'.which will list all employee with same category together.

Like,

SELECT  `e_pos` , `e_id` , `e_name`  FROM dv_test ORDER BY  `e_pos`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CI code to get your data (detailed docs on this [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)):

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
```

and then pass in following query:

```
select test.e_pos, test.e_name, inn.cnt 
from test
inner join 
    (SELECT e_pos, e_name, count(e_pos) as 'cnt' 
    FROM `test`
    group by e_pos ) inn on test.e_pos = inn.e_pos 
order by test.e_pos
```

You will get table like this, which you can then iterate to display result:[image]

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
  // echo data as desired 
}
```